# How to handle two Redactor fields in one entry page in Craft 3.3?

Tags: craft3, plugins, redactor, editor, tag

I have an entry for blogs page. It contains 2 Redactor fields named `content` and `body`. I upgraded Craft 2 to Craft 3.3. Then the old editor changed to Redactor plugin, but that Redactor worked for `body` tag and not working for `content` tag. When I take an entry with `content` tag means, getting an error like:

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>   Redactor plugin not found:
>   1. in {sitepath}/vendor/craftcms/redactor/src/Field.php

The entry works perfectly for the `body` tag.

My `standard.json` is like below:

```
{
    "buttons": ["html", "format", "bold", "italic", "lists", "link", "file","unorderedlist","orderedlist","image","video","table"],
    "plugins": ["fullscreen"],
    "toolbarFixed": true,
    "script": true,
    "paragraphize": false,
    "replaceDivs": false,
    "linebreaks": true,
    "enterKey": false,
    "replaceTags": false
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What do you see if you go to Settings → Fields **your content field**?

Comment: content is a redactor field. Body is also redactor field.